# Text following subequations is slightly indented if a label is used

Tags: math-mode, cross-referencing, indentation, mathtools

The following minimal code causes a small indentation at the beginning of the line of text, smaller than the usual indentation at the start of a paragraph. It disappears if the label in `subequations` is removed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{gather}
        a = b\\
        b = c
    \end{gather}
    \label{eqn:test}
\end{subequations}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua \ref{eqn:test}.
\end{document}
```

I haven't noticed this effect in any other maths environments - is this a bug in `subequations`?

EDIT: replace gather* with gather

Comment: The * in gather was a mistake. It was in the minimal test code

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`subequations` only plays around with the equation number and does nothing else. Therefore, placing it as the surrounding environment for `gather` actually sets it in text mode and leaves a spurious space if you don't end a line with `%`.

Solution: Insert `%` at the end of the `\label`: `\label{...}%`

Comment: All the answers were essentially the same, except you called my attention to the fact about `subequations` and it working in text mode. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Put a `%` after `\label{eqn:test}`.

```
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{gather*}
        a = b\\
        b = c
    \end{gather*}
    \label{eqn:test}%             %%<---here
\end{subequations}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua \ref{eqn:test}.
```

Actually the label should be written before the `begin{gather*}`. Then the `Lorem...` will start as a new para as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
    \label{eqn:test}%
    \begin{gather*}
        a = b\\
        b = c
    \end{gather*}
\end{subequations}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua \ref{eqn:test}.
\end{document}
```

Note: Using `\label` to a un-numbered equations doesn't mean anything (starred version does not produce equation number and hence referring to that equation!.....). Use `gather` instead.

Answer (score 5):

The `\label` is to `subequations`, so

```
\begin{subequations}\label{eqn:test}
    \begin{gather}
        a = b\\
        b = c
    \end{gather}
\end{subequations}
```

won't have spurious spaces. Notice that using `subequations` with `gather*` is meaningless: there will be no equation number to reference. You probably mean `gather`, without `*`, so each equation in the alignment will receive a subnumber.